# How to find EIGRP Neighbor located on other Switch?

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, eigrp

The [following documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/fiprrp_r/1rfeigrp.html) has been read regarding EIGRP in order to configure it on  Switch1 and 2.

The Switches are connected via a port channel. However, neither Switch1 is able to find Neighbor2 located on Switch2 nor Switch2 is able to find Neighbor1 located on Switch1.

**Configuration:**

*Switch1:*

```
router eigrp 1
 network 50.0.0.0
 eigrp router-id 50.50.50.50
 eigrp stub connected static
!
```

*Switch2:*

```
router eigrp 2
 network 50.0.0.0
 eigrp router-id 50.50.50.51
 eigrp stub connected static
!
```

**EIGRP neighbors:**

*Switch 1:*

```
Switch1#sh ip eigrp neighbors detail
EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(1)
```

*Switch 2:*

```
Switch2#sh ip eigrp neighbors detail
EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AS numbers need to match. Change either switch2 to `router eigrp 1` or change switch1 to `router eigrp 2` and reimplement the routing configuration on the device that is changed.

Comment: After following the steps from the answer, executing `sh ip eigrp neighbors detail` results in: `H Address Interface Hold Uptime SRTT RTO Q Seq \n 0 50.50.50.51 ...`. Now it works. Thank you for the answer.